# How do I install LLVM/Clang/libc++ version 3.9 on Travis-CI?

Tags: travis-ci, libc++

I know how to install LLVM/Clang/libc++ 3.8 on Travis CI, through the whitelisted `llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.8`, but this doesn't exist (or work) for 3.9.

Note the thing I need is `libc++experimental.a`, which contains the implementation of `std::experimental::filesystem` for `libc++`.

I really find the Travis-CI way of doing things kind of inflexible, so if there is a wholly alternative way of getting specific versions of things installed on a build machine, please enlighten me and free me from these stupid limitations. I also don't want to build every single toolchain dependency on Travis, that would be overkill.

Comment: Could you show how you use libc++ 3.8 on Travis CI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to get new libc++ in Travis-CI is to build it from source after installing LLVM/Clang.

Here is [the script](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/master/.travis-libcxx-setup.sh) I wrote to download, build and install libc++ for Travis, and here is an [example usage](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/master/.travis.yml) in Google Benchmarks `.travis.yml`. The script takes about 120 seconds to complete.

PS. I'm happy to see people using libc++'s `std::experimental::filesystem` :-)

Comment: This works, thanks. It would be nice if somehow this got integrated into apt.llvm.org so that we can also get nightly builds of libc++ alongside clang!

Answer (score 1):

You can [install packages with apt addon](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/#Installing-Packages-with-the-APT-Addon) into your container-based image.

Add next lines to your `.travis.yml`

```yaml
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9
    packages:
      - clang-3.9
      - libc++-dev
      - libc++abi-dev
```

Side note: At the moment you have posted your question `llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.9` [were whitelisted](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/pull/2770)

Comment: This doesn't contain the libc++ experimental extra library though